# How to configure jasypt in java spring 2.0?

Tags: java, spring, jasypt

I had a problem with Jasypt..
I can't configure jasypt in my program with Java Spring.

This is my configuration in jdbc.properties:

```
c3p0.db.driverClass = org.postgresql.Driver
c3p0.db.url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/igate-iacss
c3p0.db.user = postgres
c3p0.db.pass = ENC(5Urp3uiKn828jwkOerTslYtSSeMul0p7)
c3p0.db.initialPoolSize = 5
c3p0.db.minPoolSize = 5
c3p0.db.maxPoolSize = 20
c3p0.num.helper.thread = 5
```

My datasource code in xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd            
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd"
       default-lazy-init="false">

    <!-- turn on @Resource, @PostConstruct, and @PreDestroy  -->
    <context:annotation-config />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass">
            <value>${c3p0.db.driverClass}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="jdbcUrl">
            <value>${c3p0.db.url}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="user">
            <value>${c3p0.db.user}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
            <value>${c3p0.db.pass}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="initialPoolSize">
            <value>${c3p0.db.initialPoolSize}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="minPoolSize">
            <value>${c3p0.db.minPoolSize}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="maxPoolSize">
            <value>${c3p0.db.maxPoolSize}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="numHelperThreads">
            <value>${c3p0.num.helper.thread}</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

</beans>
```

How to configure that in java spring?
Please help me.
I hope someone can help me, just stack and can't think anymore.

Comment: Whoa is that spring 3? I haven't seen that in *years*.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the document http://www.jasypt.org/spring3.html# for integrating spring and jasypt depends upon the spring version you use.

I've created a sample spring application with jasypt. Refer to the repo here if you are looking for an example [spring-jasypt-example](https://github.com/nkumarclm/spring-jasypt)

You may need to add mvn dependency [jasypt-mvn-dependency](https://github.com/nkumarclm/spring-jasypt/blob/master/pom.xml#L34) and integrate  [jasypt-spring-configuration](https://github.com/nkumarclm/spring-jasypt/blob/master/src/main/resources/database/Spring-Datasource.xml).